# Bezier Surfaces and Control Points

Tags: graphics, bezier

I've been given the task to read the file with the information about control points and patches and to generate the solid. So far so good. Now i'm asked the opposite, i must give the control points and patch information in order to draw a Sphere. I'm completely lost here. Am i supposed to do it by hand and just keep changing values until i get sphere? Or is there an inverse method i'm not aware of.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A sphere can be exactly represented as a rational B-spline surface (with multiple patches). You can refer to this [link](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/NURBSCircleSphere.pdf) to see how to do it. Having said this, representing a sphere in this way just to draw the sphere is an expensive approach and hopefully this is just an exercise to get you be more famiiar with NURBS curve/surface.

Comment: This is not my cup of tea I am just curious but Are you sure its exact match and not just a good approximation instead?

Comment: @Spektre, Yes, it is not an approximation.  A circle can be exactly represented by a rational B-spline curve. Similarly, a sphere can be exactly represented by a rational B-spline surface.